# How do I ingest corpus data into IBM Watson?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am building a application where I am trying to use IBM Watson question & answer API.
Currently I see only corpus for Healthcare and Travel, but I would like to ingest **Custom dataset suiting my needs**. Can anyone please point me to right direction or exact API which does that or IBM already built explorer which I can use to upload the data files directly.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time you can not ingest corpus data into IBM Watson.  That is coming in the future.